# How to extract time of the day (pd.Timedelta or datetime.time) from a Datetime?

Tags: pandas, datetime, timedelta

Give a dataframe that contains a columns with `pd.Datetime`, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob'],
    'starttime': ['2020-03-20 15:05:00', '2020-03-20 15:16:00'],
})
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])
```

***How do I properly obtain the time of the day as a `pd.TimeDelta`?***

I know that one can extract the python `datetime.time` using `df['starttime'].dt.time`, but this does not help me as I want to use pandas data types (i.e. `pd.TimeDelta`) to keep time comparisons clear (I have to do a lot of comparisons and I am looking for clean code). For example, `df['starttime'].dt.time > pd.TimeDelta(13:00)` won't work. It throws the error `TypeError: Cannot compare type Timedelta with type time`, which makes sense.

I have had two ideas of how to achieve this:

1. `df['starttime'] - df['starttime'].dt.floor('1D')`: this looks "decent", but I am not sure about the implications. I doubt that it will control for those two days of the year in which the time changes, i.e. summer and winter times. I want to simply ignore those days, 11am is 11am no matter the day of the year
2. `pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'].dt.time.astype(str)`: it looks hackish, but I think it gives me what I want.

Are this methods appropriate? Is there a way to actually represent Time in pandas? For what I see there is `Datetime`, `Timedelta` and `Timestamp`.

Comment: Since you are working with time-changes, shouldn't you add timezone to your data?

Comment: I guess I oversimplified the issue in my example

Comment: you could cast the datetime column's time part to string and *then* to timedelta, e.g. `pd.to_timedelta(df['starttime'].dt.time.astype(str))`, would that help?

Comment: yes, that is my second option (see the question at the end), but I am wondering if this is the proper way? It seems a bit  hackish to me